# Implement Lazy loading with XSJS Service

Tags: sapui5, hana

I have XSJS service that returns back 3000 rows (at the minimum) to the UI. I need to implement **Lazy Loading** for the same. What is the best way to implement the same. The data is custom and hence cannot be handled by XSOData service.
I am using XS Classic to develop the XSJS Services.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, lazy loading would be implemented on the client side: delay the [JSONModel.loadData()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData) until the data is needed.

But i'm guess you will need some kind of paging, to load only parts of that many rows. If you cannot use XSOdata, you have to implement paging on your own.
Usually  some query parameters are used that define the start row and the row count to retrieve. It is often not trivial to implement paging in the service efficiently if sorting and filtering are involved.

In the UI the implementation mainly depends on what you want to do. You could just load all pages in the background using [JSONModel.loadData()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData) with `bMerge = true`. This way there are fast first rows and the list is growing while the user can start  reading. Or you can show the first rows in a list and supply a "more" button that adds the next page on demand. Or you can use classical pages like on google...